# Can't login to WSO2 using API after changing password using user update API in patch method

Tags: wso2, scim

I created a user using the API http://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users. Then I could generate access token for login using the http://localhost:9443/wso2/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&username={username}&password={password} before updating the password.
But after updating the password using http://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users/{scim_id} in PATCH method, I could not generate access token using http://localhost:9443/wso2/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&username={username}&password={password} like before.
What could be the reason? I using email address as username and I can login to console using the new password

Comment: It's better if you mention the IS version, the responses you get for access token requests, and attach the error logs printed on the terminal

Comment: 5.11.0 IS Version. Status message saying "Request failed with status code 400". No any other error log on the terminal. Please send me a solution ASAP

Comment: @JISHNUK Could you please verify the token call you have mentioned in the question? According to the documentation [1] there's a slight difference.   

[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant/